# Are there any Tkinter Widgets like OptionMenu that can be nested?

Tags: python, drop-down-menu, tkinter, nested, optionmenu

I am trying to have an OptionMenu-like list selector, but I would like to have nested options. I want them to act just like a nested menu (File->Save), but I need to grid it.

If this isn't possible (short of writing a custom widget), I will end up having two selectors, where the first picks the "main menu" and the second handles the "sub menu," but I'd really like to avoid doing that.

Comment: Maybe [pwm](http://pmw.sourceforge.net/) has something that would be useful for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Am optionmenu is just a convenience function that creates a menubutton and a menu. You can do that yourself quite easily. Here's an example:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        items = {"one": ["a","b","c"],
                 "two": ["d","e","f"],
                 "three": ["g","h","i"]}

        self.the_value = tk.StringVar()
        self.the_value.set("a")

        self.menubutton = tk.Menubutton(self, textvariable=self.the_value, indicatoron=True)
        self.topMenu = tk.Menu(self.menubutton, tearoff=False)
        self.menubutton.configure(menu=self.topMenu)

        for key in sorted(items.keys()):
            menu = tk.Menu(self.topMenu)
            self.topMenu.add_cascade(label=key, menu=menu)
            for value in items[key]:
                menu.add_radiobutton(label=value, variable = self.the_value, value=value)

        self.menubutton.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ahh, so you can place a menu anywhere, i.e. a `Menubutton`. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Improvements to code above to support longer menus. Enjoy recursion.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):

        def create_menu( top_info, top_menu, value_var):
            if isinstance(top_info, dict):
                print "Evaluating dictionary with keys:"
                for key in top_info.keys():
                    print 'Key:' + key
                    menu = tk.Menu(top_menu)
                    top_menu.add_cascade(label=key, menu=menu)
                    create_menu(top_info[key], menu, value_var)
                return
            else:
                print "Evaluating list of values:"
                for value in top_info:
                    print 'Value:' + value
                    top_menu.add_radiobutton(label=value, variable = value_var, value=value)
                return

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        items = {"one": {"a":["aa","aaa","aaaa"],"b":["bb","bb"],"c":["cc"] },
                 "two": ["d","e","f"],
                 "three": ["g","h","i"]}

        self.the_value = tk.StringVar()
        self.the_value.set("a")

        self.menubutton = tk.Menubutton(self, textvariable=self.the_value, indicatoron=True)
        self.topMenu = tk.Menu(self.menubutton, tearoff=False)
        self.menubutton.configure(menu=self.topMenu)

        create_menu(items, self.topMenu, self.the_value)

        self.menubutton.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```